# wordpress category conditional on attachment page

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, attachment, categories

How do I check the category on the image.php theme file in Wordpress?
I tried in_category('categoryname') but it did not work.
I want to use it outside of the loop. (Btw, the function also did not work inside of the loop...)
I need this to show banners according to the categories of the post.

I guess the problem is that the attachment is not associated with the category of the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `in_category("foo", $post->post_parent)`